# android intents: retrieve intent parameters

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

Assuming that the system has no errors and warnings, are there something like:

Wanted_LoginController.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(loginMVC.getLoginView(),ErrorView.class);
intent.putExtra("errorMsg", errorMsg); 
loginMVC.getLoginView().startActivity(intent);
```

Wanted_ErrorView.java:

```
Intent executedIntent = getIntent();
LoginMVC loginMVC = executedIntent.getParameter1(); //will store loginMVC context from previous intent data
ErrorView errorView = executedIntent.getParameter2(); //will store errorview from previous intent data
```

MY CUSTOM OBJECTS

ErrorView.java:

```
public class ErrorView extends Activity{
  ErrorView context;
  Bundle extras;

}
```

LoginView.java:

```
public class LoginView extends ListActivity{ 
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
    //check the device's connection to the internet
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if(mWifi.isConnected()){
      new LoginController(new LoginMVC(new LoginData(), this)); //builds a new controller for the login process    
    }else{ //blocks the user to proceed to login when internet connection is not available
      finish();
      Intent intent = new Intent(this,ErrorView.class);
      intent.putExtra("errorMsg", "Please enable Wi-Fi"); 
      startActivity(intent);
    }  
  }
}
```

LoginMVC.java:

```
public class LoginMVC{
  LoginData loginModel;
  LoginView loginView;
  LoginController loginController;

  public LoginMVC(LoginData pLoginModel, LoginView pLoginView, LoginController pLoginController){
    loginModel = pLoginModel;
    loginView = pLoginView;
    loginController = pLoginController;
  }

  public LoginMVC(LoginData pLoginModel, LoginView pLoginView){
    loginModel = pLoginModel;
    loginView = pLoginView;
  }

  public LoginController getLoginController(){
    return loginController;}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: see Intent.putExtra and Intent.getExtra

Comment: thanks for the reply but all I needed was to retrieve the parameters themselves, not the intent extras.

Comment: you mean activity names?

Comment: You put the parameters in the extras.

Comment: @Mohit: yes! the activities which are the parameters of instantiating the intent method

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah: i can't put them in the extras since it will lead to an error. putextras can't contain general object types.

Comment: They can if the Objects implements parcable

Comment: Why don't you share these objects of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean retrieving parameters of the executed intent itself?

As of now, there is still no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
especially: `getExtras()`. It returns a `Bundle` from which you can read the parameters you added to the `Intent` with `putExtra()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
You can pass a bundle to the intent at source activity and get that on destination activity.

Here is an example,

//Your source activity's code:

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            String s = "Hello world";
            bundle.putString("alpha", s);
            i = new Intent(this, DestinationActivity.class);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
```

//Your destination activity's code:

```
     Bundle  b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    if (b.containsKey("alpha")) {

          String text = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("alpha");
         // Now you can use text i.e you can show toast e.t.c


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i needed not to use bundles and extras since it can't store the CLASS contexts which are the ones that i have to retrieve, not String,char,boolean,int or floating types.